# Use applicaiton while mobile is locked android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-api

how to make application in android studio that work while mobile is locked. suppose in any emergency situation if the user swipe on mobile or press lock button 2 times it will send its location to the saved emergency numbers while mobile is locked. Any Idea?

Comment: Some of the ideas in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260986 might answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your application is not in use and you want to listen to some specific event and perform a specific task, you should use a `Service`. You can create a `LockService` as explained in this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030372/4491971

Instead of starting activity as explained in that answer, you can write your operation for sending the location to the saved emergency numbers.

```
package com.example.userpresent;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
       if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            // YOUR OPERATION CAN BE DONE HERE
        }
    }
}
```